# Entity framework where conditoon on related entity with many-to-many relation

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have many to many entities relation ships

```
Trace - Car
```

I want to select select all Traces where Car.TypeId = 1

How may i do that?

```
var traces = (from s in repository.AsQueryable<Traces>(new List<string> { "Cars" })
                                 where s.Cars.TypeId== 1//how can I put this condition on collection?
                                 select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following will do it

```
var traces = context.Traces.Where(t => t.Cars.Any(c => c.TypeId == 1));
```

This will give you a list of traces that contain a car with a TypeId of 1.